# How to run ReactJs project on server without having port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, port

*Firstly, I'm sorry for my English grammar*...

Okay, so I already run my react on the website, but when I type the site URL in the address bar, I need to even put **:3000** after the URL. If it's running on-site, I don't want to put the port on the URL.
Can anyone help me on how to run react without the port number in the deployed site?

it should look like this... **`example.site.com`** not like **`example.site.com:3000`**

If you need any details to tell me in the comments. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: You may have to remove the 3000 (hard coded string). Also, by default port 80 is used, you may find more details over here: Remove port from Node js website url

Comment: thanks ive gotten more ideas of what i got to do but problem is i dont use node its only a reactjs

Comment: Just to help you in short, you should consider watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRDkRjpg48I

Comment: im currently following the video... you should consider commenting on answer section not on comments section because if it works ill give you a check mark and upvote :)

Comment: Please watch and confirm, then I will add it as an answer otherwise people downvote unnecessarily.

Comment: when i run npm run build i had error it was about mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg write EPIPE

Comment: You should try running this command: sudo apt-get install libpng16-dev

Comment: ok but is sudo for mac? because im using m1 macos

Comment: sudo: apt-get: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm run build` and take the "build" folder that is generated and copied that folder to your server?
If you did it, its not a React problem/configuration, it's an server configuration, and depends of the server your are using. Nginx is a popular one.
If you don't run `npm run build` and you put all your project code on the server, and you are running that code with `npm start` then you are doing it your deployment in the wrong way.

Comment: i actually didnt run npm build and im runnning my site with npm start..... im new to this so pls dont be angry... ok so after i do npm build what do i do? btw thanks for fast reply to my post :) also i forgot to mention, if i put example.com it shows text because i have index.html... do i remove index.html or do something?

Comment: Don't worried, there is a starting point always. Where are you deploying your code? To a self managing server?

Comment: You can use this links: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/deploy-a-react-app-on-a-server If you are using create-react-app maybe this guide will help you: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: thanks for you kindness... so im deplying my code from vesta and filezilla... illl try the links you gave me aswell